# Redirecting https non-www to https www

Tags: ssl, redirect

I domain name registered through GoDaddy and the site hosted with Heroku.
www CNAME is pointed correctly and then I'm doing a forward on the domain to www

Everything should be pointing and redirecting to the https www version of the site.

Every combination of https/http and www/non-www works perfectly except for the following one:

**https://codefiworks.com (NOT WORKING)**

I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Unfortunately this is the url that Google has indexed for the site.

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be happening, I know just enough about DNS and SSL to be dangerous (as you can tell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server at GoDaddy that's redirecting your users from non-www to www doesn't support HTTPS.

Comment: Is this because my SSL certificate is for the www version and not the non-www?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the SSL certificate. You're using GoDaddy's redirection service, which only supports HTTP.

Comment: What's the best way to fix this? handle the redirect on the server instead?

Comment: @Brian Some people run a tiny server somewhere to do it. Others use a provider like DNS Simple for requests because they offer [an special `ALIAS` record type](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku/) (which works *like* a `CNAME` but looks like an `A` externally).